# VSTOR 4 Framework MSI Deployment via Group Policy

Tags: .net, ms-office, vsto, outlook-addin

I developed an Outlook 2010 Add-In, which is going to be deployed on hundreds of machines.
In order to deploy the add-in, I made use of the Microsoft's ClickOnce mechanism.

The add-in relies on Visual Studio Tools for Office 2010 Runtime framework (VSTOR 4). It is highly inconvenient to manually install the framework on all the machines. What will be good is some sort of an automated process to do bulk installation on clients machines. IT seems the best route to follow is to deploy pre-requisites through Group Policies. The issue here is that it accepts MSI files only. VSTOR 4 does not come in the MSI format, but EXE. Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I researched and found out that a large number of developers face this problem. And here is how I solved it.

Install 7-zip, and extract all content of the "vstor_redist.exe" to a folder. Confirm all the overwrite requests it might ask you. Navigate inside the folder and find another folder "vstor40"; navigate there and find 2 files: "vstor40_x64.exe" and "vstor40_x86.exe".
Use 7-zip to extract the content from those files. And...here you go, you have your MSI files.

Hope it would help fellow developers in future VSTO development.